# How to communicate between multiple clients?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I'm writing a Python 3 server using socket and selectors, I want to achieve communication between clients. However, I can only send the message back to the client themselves instead of other clients.

I'm confused about how to do this, could anyone help me please?

Here's the code I've written so far:

client1:

```
import socket
import sys

messages = [b'Hi from client1',
            b'Good morning from client1',
            ] 

server_address = ('localhost', 1234) 
socks = [ socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, 
socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
for i in range(1)] 

print('connecting to %s port %s' % server_address) 
for s in socks:
    s.connect(server_address)

for message in messages:
    for s in socks:
        s.send(message)
    for s in socks: 
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print(data.decode())
        if not data: 
            print(sys.stderr, 'closing socket', s.getsockname())
```

client2:

```
import socket
import sys

messages = [b'Hi from client2',
            b'Good luck from client2',
            ] 

server_address = ('localhost', 1234) 
socks = [ socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, 
socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
for i in range(1)] 

print('connecting to %s port %s' % server_address) 
for s in socks:
    s.connect(server_address)

for message in messages:
    for s in socks:
        s.send(message)
    for s in socks: 
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print(data.decode())
        if not data: 
            print(sys.stderr, 'closing socket', s.getsockname())
```

Server:

```
import selectors
import socket

sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()

def accept(sock, mask):
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    conn.setblocking(False)
    sel.register(conn, selectors.EVENT_READ, read)

def read(conn, mask):
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if data:
        conn.send(data) # echo data back to client themselves, but how to send to other client??
    else:
        sel.unregister(conn)
        conn.close()

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('localhost', 1234))
sock.listen(1)
sock.setblocking(False)
sel.register(sock, selectors.EVENT_READ, accept)

while True:
    events = sel.select()
    for key, mask in events:
        callback = key.data
        callback(key.fileobj, mask)
```

Comment: In your code, you are sending data back to the same client. You need to store the connections (`conn`) in an array and on receiving data from a client, send it to another `conn`

Comment: @SauravKumar But how to send it to another conn? I'm confused about this